# Error message when using apksigner to verify APK file

Tags: android, linux, apk, apksigner

I want to verify the fingerprint of an APK file with the apksigner tool.

With some APK files, this command gives me the desired output:

```
apksigner verify –print-certs filename.apk
```

But with other APK files, the same command gives me this error message:

```
Unexpected parameter(s) after APK (filename.apk)
```

I'm not sure if this error message means that I'm doing something wrong, or if it means that the APK file itself is not legit.

Comment: You cannot have a hyphen "-" or a space in between the app name. Try removing such characters.